# Angular State Provider throws cannot resolve State Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am very new to Angular and I am just working on an existing application where they are using state engine. I added a new state

> 'app.maintenance.population.trial'

in an existing module  which looks like following:

```
var maintenancePopulationModule = angular.module('maintenance.population.module', ['fileUpload.module'])
.config([
    '$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.maintenance.population',
            {
                url: '/population',
                templateUrl: '/app/maintenance/population/maintenance.population.view.html',
                controller: 'MaintenancePopulationController',
                authorize: true
            })
         .state('app.maintenance.population.trial',
                {
                    url: '/trial2',
                    templateUrl: '/app/maintenance/population/maintenance.population.view.html',
                    //controller: 'MaintenanceCodisController',
                    //authorize: true
                });

    }
]);
```

- As we can see, there is hardly any difference between two states. It uses the same template and added extra keyword '.trial' at the end and it stopped working. Now I did a different experiment and this time I meddled with another Module with a similar experiment:

> ```
> angular.module('maintenance.codis.module', [])
>         .config([
>             '$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
>                 $stateProvider
>                     .state('app.maintenance.codis',
>                     {
>                         url: '/codis',
>                         templateUrl: '/app/maintenance/codis/maintenance.codis.view.html',
>                         controller: 'MaintenanceCodisController',
>                         authorize: true
>                     })
>                 .state('app.maintenance.codis.trial',
>                     {
>                         url: '/trial',
>                         templateUrl: '/app/maintenance/codis/maintenance.codis.view.html',
>                         //controller: 'MaintenanceCodisController',
>                         //authorize: true
>                     });
>
>             }
>         ]);
> ```

- This one works. As you can see I there is not much difference between the states except .trial keyword at the end for these two as well. Not sure why Codis works but the population does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: update with your console errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting you to have a look about [**Nested States**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

Clearly see that **app.maintenance.codis** is your **parent** state, and **app.maintenance.codis.trial** is your **child** state.

Your Route to trial will be like this

```
...../codis/trial
```

This means that your **trial** state is a child of **codis**.
Also to check if population trial2 is working or not try accessing this Route

```
......./population/trial2
```

This must work as expected.

**FINALLY,**
To make your codis working. Ensure that there must be **ui-view** in the **Codis** html template also your both states refers to same templateUrl, modify it accordingly.

Is this answer helpful! Comment if any further explanation needed.